# Можно ли поставить Linux на отдельный жесткий диск от Windows без физического отключения?

Tags: linux, windows

Можно ли поставить Linux на отдельный жесткий диск от Windows без физического отключения диска с Windows?
Хочу поставить Manjaro на HDD. Windows находится на SSD.
Через diskmgmt.msc сжал 100 ГБ на HDD под Manjaro.

Comment: Можно. . . . . .

Comment: @andreymal а в чем подвох? Для чего это делают? Просто чтобы не запутаться в дисках или реально может что-то не так пойти?

Comment: Просто чтобы не запутаться

Comment: Пойдёт что-то не так, если ты при разбивке дисков или при установке загрузчика нажмёшь не те кнопки не в той последовательности. А так всё работает нормально.